# How to bypass ssl error Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl

I am trying to use a government DoD site `api.usno.navy.mil` to retrieve some Sun and Moon data for a weather app I am creating using Android Studio.  It seems like no matter what I do, I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

I have tried adding the DoD certs to Android Studio (although I don't have this exact cert).  I have checked "accept non-trusted certificates automatically". I have tried adding my own `HostNameVerifier`.  I have been working with the help desk for the naval observatory @navy.mil.

Nothing seems to work.  However, it does work in my Chrome Browser.

The help desk says that they are continuing to request commercially recognized certificates.

When I check the site with `https://www.digicert.com/help/`, it says the Certificate is not trusted because the certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store).

Is there any way I can force Android Studio to accept this ssl connection just so I can continue development?

**EDIT with Solution**

I solved this problem using the `getSSLSocketFactory()` from Dhanshri's suggestion below and my own `HostnameVerifier`.  Note: I only use this for the problem url mentioned above.  Here is my working code to get a connection that works:

```
   public HttpsURLConnection getUSNOHttpConnection(URL url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getUSNOHttpConnection()");

        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            // override for api.usno.navy.mil connections to prevent
            // java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification
            // path not found. errors
            HostnameVerifier usnoHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSLSocketFactory();

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(usnoHostnameVerifier);
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

Thanks to all who reviewed this question.

**EDIT Update **

On January 31, 2019 I was notified by the `api.usno.navy.mil` website help desk that they have now installed commercially recognized certificates.  I removed the bypass solution and all is working as expected with no SSL errors.